# Android get list of tables

Tags: android, database

Does anyone know the SQL to get a list of table names via code in Android? I know `.tables` does it through command shell but this doesn't work through code. Is it anything to do with the meta-data, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

Answer (score 10):

Just had to do the same. This seems to work:

```
public ArrayList<Object> listTables()
    {
        ArrayList<Object> tableList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT name FROM " + 
        "sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name"; 
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                tableList.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return tableList;
    }
```

Comment: If i print this list of tables in to log then how can it be possible ?