# What is going wrong in this?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am fetching the list of tables from the database.  I am using this code to get the list of tables:

```
public void showAllTable()
{
  db.execSQL("select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'");
}
```

This query execute successful in to the shell window.

Now I want to display that list of tables in Android.  How it is possible? I am calling this function from another activity.

Edited:
Thanks to Stack Overflow, I found [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681744/android-get-list-of-tables).

Comment: please help me regarding this. I really need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to display a list of data is to use a ListView. To do this you will need to do the following:

1: change your db query to db.query instead of db.exec and store the values in a List:

```
ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor mCursor = db.query("sqlite_master", new String[]{"name"}, "type = table",
        null,null,null,null);
if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (mCursor.moveToFirst(), !mCursor.isAfterLast(), mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        tables.add(mCursor.getString(0));
    }
}
/** Important! always close cursors and DB's */
mCursor.close();
db.close();
return tables;
```

2: Use a ListView and an ArrayAdapter to display the information. See [The Android Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) on how to do this.